# "Device" vs "Delete" pronunciation

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Why has the American English changed the pronunciation of "device" to /dəˈvaɪs/ while the word "delete" has retained its British nature which is /dɪˈliːt/ ?

Both words are just too close to allow for such a discrepancy.

Comment: Don't forget to compare with other words, like *deny*, *delay*, and so on.

Comment: I think we use the schwa in both... I certainly don't pronounce the first syllables any differently.  Here's a bunch of samples to flip through: https://youglish.com/pronounce/delete/english?

Comment: Dictionaries vary in how they describe unstressed vowels. Luckily, variation between individuals' pronunciation is much broader than the dictionaries', so you can take any of them you prefer, and somebody else will take a different one.

Comment: @JohnLawler I distinctly hear the ɪ sound when this word "device" is pronounced by the British, while the American say something quite different, so I'm not sure about the unstressed vowel. Here's another such word, "believe" - which for some reasons goes with **ɪ** instead of **ə** both in UK and USA. So, what's wrong with device? ;-)

Comment: Once again, individuals vary widely, in every population. If you wanted a detailed analysis, you'd have to do a sociophonetic survey -- two actually, one in the US and one in the UK. Of course they'd only delimit the area and individuals you surveyed, not the whole country. It's a very expensive undertaking, and therefore seldom done.

Answer (score 1):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has pronunciations
**device** Brit. /dᵻˈvʌɪs/, U.S. /dəˈvaɪs/, /diˈvaɪs/
**delete** Brit. /dᵻˈliːt/, U.S. /dəˈlit/, /diˈlit/
which denies your British/American difference for these two words.

---

It seems ᵻ means "free variation between /ɪ/ and /ə/".